# How to return to same page with selected data after file upload in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, model-view-controller

I am trying to upload a file. After file upload, the page should be visible with the previous data.
What  I have done:

I have two users agronomist and a grower. If I choose a grower, the grower profile should be visible, and upload the file in the grower profile, but after file upload, the selected grower data is not visible. how to make selected data visible after file upload.
What I have tried is:

blade.php

```
<div class="agronomist_div">
<form class="form-horizontal" >
    <h1 class="text-center">Account Information</h1>
   

 <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="growers_lsit">Growers List:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="growers_list" onchange="fetchGrower();">
           
            <option value="">Select Growers</option>
             @foreach($grower_data as $data)
             <option value="{{$data->first_name}},{{$data->id}}">{{$data->first_name}} </option>
             @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="grower-data-div">
    <div id="grower_form" class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Grower Profile</h1>
     <div class="row text-center">
        
            
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="beets" placeholder="Beets" id="grower_name" class="form-control" value="" readonly="">
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
             <input type="text" name="beets" placeholder="Primary Crop" class="form-control">
        </div>

        </div>
 
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                   <h3>Recommendations </h3>
        </div>
            </div>
   
 <form method="POST" action="/uploadRecommends" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
 <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="grower_id" value="" id="grower_id">
     
     <div class="container mt-3 mb-3">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="input-group mt-3">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file"  name="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">Choose file</label>+
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-append">
  <label class="input-group-text " id="">+</label>
  </div>
    
</div>
             </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group pt-3">
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload PDF" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
         </div>
         </div>    
   </div>
 </div>
   
  </form>

            <div class="row container">
         <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="table" class="table table-bordered text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PDF Name </th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                   
                    <th>View</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
         </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

javascript file

```
<script>
function fetchGrower()
     {
           var e = document.getElementById("growers_list");
var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
var opArr=option.value.split(",");
var grower_id=opArr[1];
var grower_name=opArr[0];

 $.ajax({
         url: 'fetchPdf/'+grower_id,
         type: 'get',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response){
             $('#table tbody').empty(); 
             $("#grower-data-div").css("display", "block");
             $("#grower_name").val(grower_name);
             $("#grower_id").val(grower_id);
                var len=response['data'].length;
           if(len > 0){
              for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                 var pdf_name = response['data'][i].pdf_name;
                 var pdf_date = response['data'][i].pdf_date;
                 var pdf_id = response['data'][i].id;
                  var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                  
                   "<td align='center' style='width:20vw;'>" +pdf_name + "</td>" +
                   "<td align='center'>" + pdf_date + "</td>" +
                   "<td align='center'><a href='/openPdf/"+pdf_name+"'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></td>" +
                 "<td align='center'><a href='/deleteFile/"+pdf_id+"'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></td>"
            "</tr>";

                 $("#table tbody").append(tr_str);
              }
              
     }
     else{
              var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                  "<td align='center' colspan='4'>No record found.</td>" +
              "</tr>";

              $("#table tbody").append(tr_str);
           }
     
 }
     });
     }
</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/uploadRecommends', 'HomeController@uploadRecommends');
Route::get('/fetchPdf/{id}', 'HomeController@fetchPdf');
```

HomeController.php

```
  public function uploadRecommends(Request $request)
    {
        $grower_id=$request->input('grower_id');
        $agronomist_id=auth()->user()->id;
        if(array_key_exists('file', $request->all()))
        {
            $pdf_file=$request->file;
             $name=$pdf_file->getClientOriginalName();
             $filename = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
             $extension = $pdf_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
             $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $pdf_file->storeAs('public/cca_license/pdf_upload',$fileNameToStore);
           DB::insert('insert into grower_recommends(agronomist_id,grower_id,pdf_name) values(?,?,?)',[$agronomist_id,$grower_id,$fileNameToStore]);
        echo "<script>alert('File Uploaded Successfully');window.location.href='/agronomist_account';</script>";
           
        }
    }
 public function fetchPdf($gro_id)
    {
        
        $res=DB::table('users')->where('id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
         $first_name=$res[0]->first_name;
         $last_name=$res[0]->last_name;
         $name=$first_name." ".$last_name;
       //  $res1=DB::table('user_role')->where('id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
         $agro_data= DB::table('user_roles')
->select('user_roles.roles_id','users.first_name','users.id')
->join('users','users.id','=','user_roles.user_id')

->where('user_roles.roles_id','=',2)
->get();
         
        $pdf_data=DB::table('grower_recommends')->where('agronomist_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('grower_id',$gro_id)->latest('pdf_date')->get();
        $userData['data'] = $pdf_data;
        echo json_encode($userData);
     exit;
        //return view('grower_account')->with('pdf_data',$pdf_data)->with('name',$name)->with('agro_data',$agro_data);
    }
```

When I select a user, the page shows data like this.

[![Output1][1]][1]

After uploading file, the page shows output as

[![Output2][2]][2]

How to show the user data , after file upload.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z0RQ.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peg2K.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$request->flash();
return redirect()->back();
```

Or

```
session()->flashInput();
return redirect()->back();
```

[Check Flashing inputs into session, laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#flashing-input-to-the-session)
Or [Flashing request data into session for next requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data)

Comment: Not working, how to return to the page with the previous data

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: flashinput() shows error

Answer (score 0):

In controller( method fetchPdf()) return $pdF_data without assigning to any array.

Comment: fetchPdf is json data, the uploading file function uploadRecommends()

Answer (score 0):

(1) */uploadRecommends* this route call form the ajax function and then after you need to call the *fetchGrower* function in blade file

without page refresh...

(2) you can use [Laravel Http session](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session)  to use for store data of grower or agronomist in session using the session you can just redirect respected page or blade file.

Comment: Not working, how to get previous data in select